# How to prove the following theorem-

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let {${f_n}$} be a  sequence in $L^p$ which converges in the mean of order $p$ to $f$ in $L^p$.Then prove-

- If the sequence {$f_n$} converges in the mean of order $p$ to $g$,then $f=g$ almost every where.
- The sequence {$f_n$} is a $p-mean$ cauchy sequence.
- $\lim_{n\to \infty}||f_n||_p = ||f||_{p}$,in particular the sequence {$f_n$} is bounded with respect to the norm $||.||_{p}$

> What I tried for first part:
>
> using contradiction:Suppose $f≠g$ a.e then $f$ & $g$ are not
>   equivalent functions.Which means $f$ and $g$ will not belong to same
>   $Lp$ space simultaneously.which contradicts the hypothesis that $f$
>   converges to $g$ in mean of order $p$.Hence,f=g a.e.
>
> Is it correct?

While collecting the key points regarding above theorem from many books,ive encountered several examples which justifies the above theorem but i'm not getting how to prove it generally.

I've given  it a large amount of time.So it would be better if someone please provide the proof of the above theorem.

Comment: If you know how to show that limits of sequences are unique, the first one is done.

Comment: @SeanRoberson:I know how to show  uniqueness of limits in reals but not in $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: Can you show us what you did yet ?

Comment: @Marine1:Wait!:-)

Comment: @Marine1:I tried it using contradiction:Suppose $f \neq g$ a.e then $f$ & $g$ are not equivalent functions.Which means $f $ and $g$ will not belong to same $L^p$ space simultaneously.which contradicts the hypothesis that $f$ converges to $g$ in mean of order $p$.Hence,$f=g$   a.e.

Comment: @Marine1:This is all what i concluded from my research regarding the O.P

Comment: Nice attempt but may $f$ & $g$ be not equivalent functions I don't no why that would mean that $f$ and $g$ would not belong to same $L_p$, at least I haven't yet a proof of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted solution does not really make sense. The idea is to follow the same proof that limits (in $\mathbb R$, for example) are unique, but replace equality with a.e. equality. Specifically, fix $\varepsilon>0$. By definition of $L^p$ convergence, there exists $n_1$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_p<\frac\varepsilon2$ for all $n\ge n_1$, and there exists $n_2$ such that $\|f_n-g\|_p<\frac\varepsilon2$ for all $n\ge n_2$. Let $n=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. Then
$$\|f-g\|_p=\|f-f_n+f_n-g\|_p\le\|f-f_n\|_p+\|f_n-g\|_p<\tfrac\varepsilon2+\tfrac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\|f-g\|_p=0$, so $\int|f-g|^p=\|f-g\|_p^p=0$. This implies $|f-g|^p=0$ a.e. and so $f=g$ a.e.

Note how closely this matches the usual proof that limits in $\mathbb R$ are unique. See if you can similarly mimic the respective proofs for your other two questions.

Comment: I agree with you, I was really wondering why supposing $f≠g$ a.e implying that $f$ & $g$ are not equivalent functions would mean that $f$ and $g$ would not belong to same $Lp$ space simultaneously. They can, isn't it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're saying. I suggest you take another look at the definition of equality almost everywhere and the $L^p$ spaces.